# Can I eliminate the nested if-else from my solution to this FizzBuzz-style pro​blem?

Tags: java, refactoring

I have been given following problem to solve.

- If the integer is divisible by 3, return the string "Java".
- If the integer is divisible by 3 and divisible by 4, return the
  string "Coffee"
- If the integer is one of the above and is even, add "Script" to the
  end of the string. Otherwise, return the string "mocha_missing!

Sample Input and Output

- caffeineBuzz(1) => "mocha_missing"
- caffeineBuzz(3) => "Java"
- caffeineBuzz(6) => "JavaScript"
- caffeineBuzz(12) => "CoffeeScript"

And my solution is as follows:

```
//Class 

public class CoffieScriptGenerator {

    public String caffeineBuzzz(Integer number) {

        if(isDivisbleByThreeAndFour(number))
        {
            if(isEven(number))
            return "CoffeeScript";
            else
            return "Coffee";
        }
        if(isDivisbleByThree(number))
        {
            if(isEven(number))
            return "JavaScript";
            else
            return "Java";
        }
        return "mocha_missing!";


    }

    private boolean isEven(Integer number) {
        return number%2==0; 
    }

    private boolean isDivisbleByThreeAndFour(Integer number) {

        return isDivisbleByThree(number) && number%4==0;
    }

    private boolean isDivisbleByThree(Integer number) {
        return number%3==0;
    }

}
```

Please provide suggestions to refactor it and improve it and how I can improve such nesting if-else with the help of patterns like Strategy.

Comment: This is a class problem known as "FizzBuzz" and has many answers, all of which are opinions. Because this is an opinionated question, it does not belong on StackOverflow. It is however, a wonderful question to throw on [CodeReview.StackExchang](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You may find that your question has already been addressed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79389/fizzbuzz-challenge). But, because the answers vary from implementation to implementation, you can still ask your question on CodeReview.

Comment: thanks matthew for your suggestion sure i will post in mention side

Comment: No problem. You should delete this question though, so it doesn't promote other users to ask the same questions on this site. And to continue to learn and improve your code, you should do whatever projects you would like to. After you finish a project or once you get to a certain point, you can post it on CodeReview and ask for suggestions for improvement. If you run into any programming problems like errors, you can ask on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good design pattern for these sorts of problems is to start with an empty string at the top. Then as your code flows downward and checks for certain conditions, you append text to the end of your string as you go. Then, by the time you reach the end of the method, your string is all built and you can simply return it.

The advantage of this type of design is that your method only has one exit point (only one return statement).

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion but actually how to get ride of these nested if is what i am looking for because during regular coding i use lot of if else in my code please provide some links where i can practice or do pair programing and get  suggestions on improvement.